# How could i create a TreeView like Microsoft apps

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, window

Hi im training to develop an app but i want to add a tree with a specific appearance i succeed  in doing that but the appearance of what i have is not what my clients want the app is developed using MFC and C++.

**My app looks like this:**

[image]

**I want it to look like this:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**The code I'm using:**

```
CRect rectDummy(0,0,200,600);
//rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();

CTreeCtrl m_wndClassView;

const DWORD dwViewStyle = WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_LINESATROOT | TVS_HASBUTTONS | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN;

if (!m_wndClassView.Create(dwViewStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndView, 2))
{
    TRACE0("Failed to create Class View\n");
    return -1;      // fail to create
}


HTREEITEM hRoot = m_wndClassView.InsertItem(_T("System Summary"), 0, 0);
m_wndClassView.SetItemState(hRoot, TVIS_BOLD, TVIS_BOLD);

HTREEITEM hClass = m_wndClassView.InsertItem(_T("Hardwre Resources"), 1, 1, hRoot);
hClass = m_wndClassView.InsertItem(_T("Components"), 1, 1, hRoot);
hClass = m_wndClassView.InsertItem(_T("Software Enviroment"), 1, 1, hRoot);
```

> I prefer the solution to be in MFC/C++ if possible and not using a third party libraries.

Comment: [Tree View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759988.aspx).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add dependency to the `uxtheme.lib` library, include the `<Uxtheme.h>` header, call the [SetWindowTheme()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827(v=vs.85).aspx) function after you've created the control:

```
SetWindowTheme(hYourTreeviewHandle, L"Explorer", NULL);
```

which will give your treeview control a Windows Explorer look and feel. Things are much more involved as you need to supply your own image list and also utilize the [TreeView_SetImageList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760056(v=vs.85).aspx) macro to attach the image lists to the treeview:

```
TreeView_SetImageList(hYourTreeviewHandle, hYourImagesHandle, TVSIL_NORMAL);
```

Comment: Hi could you tell me about how to remove the dots also "the doted line between the elements"

Comment: @Karim Remove the `TVS_HASLINES` and `TVS_LINESATROOT` window styles from your `const DWORD dwViewStyle=...` code. More on the treeview styles can be found on [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 6):

You need a couple of things to get this look:

1. Make sure that your application manifest specifies comctl32 v6.
2. Add a call to `SetWindowTheme(hTreeView, L"explorer", NULL)` after you create the tree view. Here `hTreeView` is the window handle of the tree view.